# DRF - Serialize and Deserialize further explanation

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am starting to work with [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and I am a little confused with [Serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers), sometimes its called to serialize and sometimes to deserialize, sometimes is called with the `data` param, and sometimes it doesn't. When and how is a good use for serializers to serialize and deserialize?

Answer (score 5):

Serialization is the process of preparing your data to be sent ower the network in the case of REST. The result of the serialization is a json/xml in the case of Django REST framework. So you need to serialize your data when you get it, and you deserialize it when you save it to the model with a POST/PUT request.

For further reading: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Answer (score 0):

**Serialization**: Converting complex data types like queryset to native data types like dictionary.
**DeSerialization**: Converting python native data types to Complex data types.

so both the actions are accomplished with the same serializer. basically when we call a serializer with parameter data (like serializer=Serializer(data=data_dict), it return a complex object. and when we call it with complex object, it gives a dictionary.

So basically there is nothing like deserializer. Serializers perform both serialization and deserialization depending on the parameter we pass and that's how we call it.

we serializer data to send over the network so that it can be easily interpreted and rendered easily in the browser. we deserialize data to get complex object and to probably save it to database.

Thanks! Hope you find this helpful.:)

Answer (score 0):

Serialization:

Complex Data type --> (serialize) Python Native Data type --> JSON

Converting Complex data types (like queryset) into Python Native Data type(like dictionary) is called serialization. This Python native data type (dictionary) is FURTHER converted into JSON object so that it can be used in frontend applications.

Deserialization (vice-versa of serialization):

JSON --> (Deserialize) Python Native Data type --> Complex Data type (that is stored in Database)